# Multiple Instances Of Applications in Parental Controls - Allowed Apps List After Snow Upgrade

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, parental-controls, multiple-instances

After upgrading several systems from Leopard to Snow Leopard there are now multiple instances of several applications listed in the System Preferences > Parental Controls > Allowed Apps

The applications may be duplicated 2 or 3 times in the list.

Why are there multiples in the list ?

Additionally...

Creating a new account on said systems does not reveal copies of apps in the Parental Controls list.

Does anyone know how to refresh the list of applications in Parental Controls for an existing account ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the rather mundane and less than ideal solution to this question is:

1. System Preferences > Accounts> Uncheck"Enable parental controls".
2. Restart
3. System Preferences > Accounts> Check"Enable parental controls".

Now all the extra instances are gone from the Allowed Apps in Parental Controls.

The downside is that you then need to re-check or un-check the apps as desired.

Would be great to have a unix command to do a more elegant job of it.